# Meteor environment variables invalid in production

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, environment-variables

I am using Meteor UP for deployment and have set the environment variable both in the mup.json file and a file server/lib/env.js which contains them.

Here is where its being accessed:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  // Remove configuration entries in case service is already configured
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
      service: "facebook"
  });

  // Add Facebook configuration entry
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    "service": "facebook",
    "appId": process.env.FACEBOOK_1,
    "secret": process.env.FACEBOOK_2
  });

});
```

However in the browser I'm getting "Invalid app id: null", but it works in development, any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, using `Meteor.settings` rather than environment variables may be more robust. Also, you don't need to wrap the configuration in a `Meteor.startup` invocation. I also use Meteor Up.

Comment: I tried removing start up and it broke the app saying no method "remove"

Comment: So how do I go about using Meteor.settings? Do I declare them in a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Meteor.settings.

#### Development

Define settings in `.config/development/settings.json`.
Create shell script (`dev.sh`) in root of your meteor project:

```
#!/bin/bash
meteor --settings .config/development/settings.json
```

Instead using command `meteor` run `./dev.sh`

#### Production (deploy using mup)

`mup init` creates 'deployment directory' with generated files `mup.json` and `settings.json`.

It is important to execute `mup init` outside of your meteor app directory, so deployment configuration will not be stored on app server.

### Usage

Example of `settings.json`:

```
{
    "service_id":"...",
    "service_secret":"...",
    "public":{
        "service_name":"..."
    }
}
```

> If the settings object contains a key named public, then
>   Meteor.settings.public will be available on the client as well as the
>   server. All other properties of Meteor.settings are only defined on
>   the server.

**server only**:

```
Meteor.settings.service_id
Meteor.settings.service_secret
```

**server and client** :

```
Meteor.settings.public.service_name
```

#### Update:

Changed paths accordingly to `Hubert OG`'s comment

Comment: Note: you should keep those files in a hidden directory, i.e. `/.config` instead of `/config`. You usually keep private API keys in those files and don't want them sent to the client. While Meteor normally doesn't touch `.json` files, it is possible that a package you add later does. Hiding these files will prevent them being compiled and sent to the world.

Comment: Still saying invalid app id null, I have filled in settings.json in my .deploy folder and now user Meteor.settings